# Problem in adding IP to Platform Designer

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I'm new to Platform Designer and I want to add an **ALT PLL intel FPGA IP** to a Platform Designer project, but after opening Mega wizard plugin manager and setting up the requirements, the IP does not add to the project.

**qurtus version:** Quartus Prime lite edition 20.1.
**operating system:** Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
**Device Family:** Max 10.

I found a [link](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Quartus-Prime-Software/Linux-Qsys-Now-quot-platform-designer-quot-ALT-PLL-Altera-FPGA/td-p/655493) from the Intel website that refers to the same problem, but without asolution.

**More description:**
I can add any other IP core, but my only problem is with this particular IP and there is no problem in the Windows version.

Comment: Please note: you'll have better luck posting on Intel's FPGA forums.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that qmegawiz command returns with status 1 which means "Cancel", so the tcl interprets the result as the user had clicked "Cancel" instead of "Finish". As a dirty hack I changed the following line

```
if { $status != 0 } {
```

to

```
if { $status != 0 && $status != 1} {
```

in ~/intelfpga_lite/20.1/ip/altera/sopc_builder_ip/altera_avalon_mega_common/sopc_mwizc.tcl

and it works. The "Cancel" button doesn't work after this of course but it's a far smaller issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can resolve most of your Intel FPGA related problems

1. Check for KDB or "Knowledge Database" on Intel website for bugs in SW / Silicon etc
2. Use one revision of Quartus lower than the problem version
3. Please include a screenshot of the problem and a better description than "IP does not add to project". Are you sure you are doing everything right ? Ensure you watch the YouTube "How to" videos from Intel FPGA channel.

Comment: Thanks. I did same thing in windows version and it works. my problem is with linux version.

Comment: My problem  is as simple as I mentioned. but for more details I add a link at the end of question.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on Ubuntu, the wizard shows, and the component appears in System Contents. Then when I click Finish on the wizard, the component disappears from System Contents without any error.